# Remove duplicated value in a same row in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am working with a large dataset which about 300k rows in R,  and I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out. My data currently looks like this:

```
G01 G01 G02
G02 G04
C01 C01 B01
H01 H07 D07 H01
```

My question is how to delete the duplicated value in a row, what I want to get is:

```
G01 G02 
G02 G04
C01 B01 
H01 H07 D07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unique` to *Remove duplicated values*.

```
lapply(x, unique)
#[[1]]
#[1] "G01" "G02"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "G02" "G04"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "C01" "B01"
#
#[[4]]
#[1] "H01" "H07" "D07"
```

Data:

```
x <- list(c("G01","G01","G02"), c("G02","G04"), c("C01","C01","B01"),
 c("H01","H07","D07","H01"))
```

In case you have stored it in a vector you can use `strsplit` before and `paste` afterwards.

```
x <- c("G01 G01 G02", "G02 G04", "C01 C01 B01", "H01 H07 D07 H01")
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), function(y) paste(unique(y), collapse = " "))
#[1] "G01 G02"     "G02 G04"     "C01 B01"     "H01 H07 D07"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. Assuming your data `df` is a dataframe you can use `separate_rows()` to open the values with delimitator space and then remove the duplicated values. Finally you can use `summarise()` in order to get the expected result. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep=' ') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(value)) %>%
  summarise(value=paste0(value,collapse = ' ')) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-id)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  value      
  <chr>      
1 G01 G02    
2 G02 G04    
3 C01 B01    
4 H01 H07 D07
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("G01 G01 G02", "G02 G04", "C01 C01 B01", 
"H01 H07 D07 H01")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```